# not able get the rows in the grid zk java

Tags: zk, zul, zk-grid

I have following code where I am adding the row to the group.

When I trying to fetch the rows by using grid.getRows.getChildren() is giving me the empty rows.

```
<template name="model">
  <zk if="${forEachStatus.index == 0}">
        <group label="refund" />
  </zk>
  <row if ="${forEachStatus.index != 0}">
    <cell>
    <inbox value="${forEachStatus.index}" />
    </cell>
    <cell>
    <input value="${each}" />
    </cell>
 </row>
```

How we retrieve from the template.

Comment: can you please give your viewmodel or controller part also?

Comment: I have missed to call renderall(). After adding it I can see the rows properly

Comment: when using a model it is recommended to change the objects in the model, and reflect the model state when rendering the template